# Makefile, removing several files in clean option

Tags: linux, makefile

In my makefile file I have the line

```
rm -f ${filename}.{log,aux,out}
```

but does not works, but if I write the same line in the terminal works perfectly. **What I must to add to my makefile to do this?**

The ideas is remove all the files with prefix $filename and extension .log, .aux and .out, for example:

```
rm -f ${filename}.log ${filename}.aux ${filename}.out
```

works well, but I have a lot of extensions and thats why I'm looking for resolve this as in the first code.

Comment: Brace expansion is a bash feature. You would have to make sure your Makefile uses bash and not sh.

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy , with your hint I solved my problem: just adding SHELL=/bin/bash to my makefile. Or you suggest other better idea?